# Writing a query that optionally only shows records between dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a MySQL query as part of a Laravel project which will allow me to only return records that match specific conditions.

For this solution, I have the following database migration:

```
Schema::create('slides', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('order')->default(0);
    $table->boolean('enabled')->default(0);
    $table->dateTime('start')->nullable();
    $table->dateTime('end')->nullable();            
});
```

This will be queried as follows, theoretically (this isn't correct SQL!):

```
SELECT * FROM slides
IF enabled == 1
    IF start IS NOT NULL
        Only return the record if the current timestamp is after start
    IF end IS NOT NULL
        Only return the record if the current timestamp is before end
ORDER BY order ASC
```

It's important to bear in mind that neither start nor end is dependent on the other - I can set a start date and no end date, and have it appear from the start date indefinitely. The same applies to the end date.

I have some working code, adapted from the current answers, which seems to work correctly, but looks very convoluted:

```
SELECT *
 FROM slides
WHERE `enabled` = 1
    AND ((`start` < NOW() AND `end` > NOW()) OR (`start` IS NULL AND `end` > NOW()) OR (`start` < NOW() AND `end` IS NULL) OR (`start` IS NULL AND `end` IS NULL))
ORDER BY `order`
```

**FOLLOW-UP**
With the help of Spencer's solution (the accepted solution), I successfully created the Eloquent code to enable me to perform this query. For reference, here it is:

```
$slides = Slide::where('enabled', true)
    ->where(function($query) {
        return $query->where('start', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
            ->orWhereNull('start');
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
        return $query->where('end', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
            ->orWhereNull('end');
    })                  
    ->orderBy('order', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Be careful with `order`. It's a MySQL reserved word and requires special attention. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I understand. I figured I'd put it in quotes when I am actually writing the query.

Comment: that should be ticks actually `\`` not quotes `'` ;-) 2 different animals here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ahh damnit, I know it's ticks, too, I just called them quotes by accident. (And I couldn't figure how to put ticks in my code in my question!)

Comment: The query in the update to the question looks it might be right, but it could be expressed a little shorter...   `AND ( \`start\` < NOW() OR \`start\` IS NULL ) AND ( \`end\` > NOW() OR \`end\` IS NULL )`

Comment: @Furze *hee hee*, no worries ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a query like this would satisfy the requirements. (I'm assuming that `->dateTime` indicates that the MySQL column is defined as datatype `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.)

```
 SELECT s.id
      , s.order
      , s.enabled
      , s.start
      , s.end 
   FROM slides s
  WHERE s.enabled = 1
    AND ( s.start <= NOW() OR s.end >= NOW() )
  ORDER BY s.order
```

We take the specification "current timestamp is after start" to mean "start column is less than or equal to the current timestamp". And we take the specification to mean "end is greater than or equal to current timestamp".  (One question there is the corner case of the equality condition, when start or end exactly matches the current timestamp.)

**FOLLOWUP**

The query above doesn't handle the cases where `start` or `end` are NULL.

I think I better understand the specification now (based on the comments and the update to the question.)

OP is looking to return rows where the current datetime (now) is between the start and end...  essentially the "slides" that are currently active.

But OP wants to consider a NULL value in `start` the same as "before now", and a   NULL value in `end` as being the same as "after now".

That could be expressed like this:

```
 SELECT s.id
      , s.order
      , s.enabled
      , s.start
      , s.end 
   FROM slides s
  WHERE s.enabled = 1
    AND ( s.start < NOW() OR s.start IS NULL )
    AND ( s.end   > NOW() OR s.end   IS NULL )
  ORDER BY s.order
```

Comment: Would that work for cases where either start or end, or both, are left as NULL?

Comment: @Furze: No, I missed the case for both `start` and `end` are null. I'll fix it.

Comment: I've updated my question with some code which appears to be working, but looks really messy - I based it mainly off this answer. Does it look like it's about right?

Comment: Yes, that looks like what you were asking for.  I think I understand now the behavior you were after... treating a NULL value for START as being the same as "earlier than now". and treating a NULL value for END as being the same as "later than now".  you are looking for rows where the current timestamp is between the start and end. i think there's a more elegant way to specify that...

Answer (score 2):

@strawberry mentioned it already in his comment but nobody picked up on it:

```
select * from slides where
coalesce(start,'1900-1-1')<now()
and coalesce(end,'3000-12-31')>now()
```

The chosen dates like `'1900-1-1'` etc. are supposed to be picked as "before" and "after" any expectable date.

This way a meaningful comparison of dates only takes place if the date has actually a value.

Comment: That's pretty handy. So I basically leave the `1900-1-1` and `3000-12-31` as they are? Your answer seems to be the cleanest and shortest. It also seems to work perfectly!

I presume then, this works as I mentioned, with either start or end, both, or none set? I tacked on the ordering and the enabled test, and it all looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic is something like this:

```
select s.*
from slides s
where ((enabled = 1 and start is not null and current_timestamp > start) and
       (enabled = 1 and end is not null and current_timestamp < end)
      ) or
      (enabled <> 1 or enabled is null) 
order by order asc;
```

Comment: Would that work with either start or end set, as well as both or neither? (Now that's an odd sentence to write!)